# Writing 3D polygon using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, 3d

I am working on some scripts with 3D polygons using ArcPy (ArcGIS 10). Reading and data manipulation works fine.  However, writing the output back into a shapefile does not seem to work, it only generated 2D files. For writing I use the following function:

```
import arcpy    
def write_new_MP(data,outfile):
        array = arcpy.Array()
        point = arcpy.Point()
        features=[]
        for feature in data:
            for part in feature:         
                point.X=part[0]
                point.Y=part[1]
                point.Z=part[2]
                array.add(point)
            MP=arcpy.Polygon(array,None,True,True)
            array.removeAll()
            features.append(MP)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, outfile,"", "0", "0", "0")
        return
```

the data is a list like`data=[[[5,5,5],[10,5,5],[10,10,5],[5,10,5],[5,5,5]],[[15,15,15],[10,15,15],[10,10,15],[15,10,15],[15,15,15]]]`

Does somebody know why the Z-values aren't used when generating the output?

Comment: How have you confirmed that the Z isn't written to the file?  Are you viewing this in the 3D analyst?

Comment: by viewing in arcscene, all objects appear flat no matter what z-data is written

Comment: Are you using an existing feature class or are you creating the fc as part of this script? If it is part of the script can you post that portion as well? How are you setting the coordinate system, etc?

Comment: Depending on your data you might also need to include another nested loop to account for multi-part features (an array of arrays). So it would go Features -> Parts -> Vertices.

Comment: Bringing an old post back from the dead.  Can you try enabling the environment variable "outputZFlag" to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Let me say first that I spent few minutes learning what GIS is and few more minutes learning what arcpy is.  In addition, I do not have required software to check your code.  However, the similarity of your code and the code at [Arc Gis Resource Center-Desktop10-polygon example-Create a polyline feature class from scratch](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000n1000000) is striking.  What is missing in your code is the following.

"Add the first point of the array in to close off the polygon"

```
array.add(array.getObject(0))
```

in between your lines

```
array.add(point)
MP=arcpy.Polygon(array,None,True,True)
```

Did you try that already?